# What are some good ways to localize a boolean value?

Tags: ios, swift

For String, we can perform localization in the following manner.

```
Localizable.strings
-------------------
"created_time" = "Created time";

Source code
-----------
extension String: Localizable {
    public var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }
}

let localizedString = "created_time".localize
```

But, what about a boolean value? For instance, I want the `defaultValue` to be `true`, for Chinese speaking users, but `false` for others.

```
static var isShowLunarCalendar: Bool {
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "SHOW_LUNAR_CALENDAR")
    }
    get {
        // TODO: How to localize this boolean variable?
        let defaultValue = false
        UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "SHOW_LUNAR_CALENDAR", defaultValue)
    }
}
```

May I know, what are some good ways to localize a boolean value?

Comment: You aren't really asking about localising a Boolean in the same way that you localise a string. What you are really asking about it changing the defaults for settings. There probably isn't a "one size fits all" approach to this.  For the example you gave, you might consider getting `Calendar.current` and checking its `identifier` against `.chinese`  This way your app adapts to the users *settings*, not their *language*; a person who prefers to use their device in Chinese may use the Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
 let res = Bool("BoolLocalize".localize)! // res is a true Bool in ch
```

**ch.local**

```
"BoolLocalize" = "true";
```

**other.local**

```
"BoolLocalize" = "false";
```